# Can appositives rename a verb?

Tags: modifiers, parentheticals, appositives

While researching, I discovered the existence of 'summative' and 'resumptive' modifiers, which are both types of appositive.

For context, here is an example of a summative modifier:

> He saw the building, a desolate structure made of brick and cement.

And a resumptive modifier:

> He saw the house, the house at the end of the street.

Traditionally, appositives are said to rename a noun or noun phrase. However, some examples seem to contradict this:

> He whispered to her, an action that received an unwanted response.

> He whispered to her, whispered soothingly.

Here, the summative modifier summarises a verb, and the resumptive modifier restates the verb. This doesn't fall into the same category as standard apposition.

Comment: Both of those are appositive noun phrases. If you want to call them summative and resumptive modifiers, go right ahead, but don't expect anybody else to understand what you mean.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, it is true that those examples are appositives. But that was not the question. Here is an example of what I mean: 'He whispered to her, an action that received an unwanted response.' Here the parenthetical noun phrase has no noun to correlate with in the main clause. It effectively describes 'whispered,' which is a verb.

Comment: He whispered to her [which was] an action that received an unwanted response. For me, which was is implied. And a repetition of a verb is not an appositive. It's a poetry mechanism.

Comment: A matter of style, then. A lot of the articles I was reading were intending to improve prose, so that make sense. In regard to the use of 'which,' it seems that a lot of grammatical problems can be justified by ellipsis. Reduced relatives are often a safe bet.

Comment: There's an argument that any parenthetical in-line reformulatory/explanatory element is an appositive. 'The mistreatment of slaves was egregious [awful].'  / 'The youths absquatulated [scarpered].' /  'Don't spill the beans [give the game away]'. This boils down to choice of stipulative definition.

Answer (score 1):

Apposition would imply that you could replace the 'anchor' with the phrase that is in apposition to it and maintain the same meaning. This is not possible in the examples given.

The strings on the right could not replace those on the left while maintaining the same meaning.

> He whispered to her. =/= An action that received an unwanted response.
>
> He whispered to her. =/=  He whispered soothingly.

The two examples given are not examples of apposition, but rather an ascriptive NP acting as supplement with the whole clause *He whispered to her* as anchor in the first, and a coordination in the second as the two elements in coordination can be reversed without a change in meaning.

> He whispered to her. That was an action that received an unwanted response.
>
> He whispered soothingly; he whispered to her.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in a sentence containing "noun + appositive" both serve as a subject or object and either can be omitted. For a verb, similar conditions must be extant, i.e. either verb/lexical verb/verb phrase can be used. In "He whispered to her, whispered soothingly." this is not the case. -- "He struck out, expunged, the offending word." - either verb can serve on its own but one is more precise or adds to the other. However, I don't think this can be called an appositive.